# travis-ci kivy release error

Tags: python, kivy, travis, travis-ci

Пытаюсь скомпилировать свое приложение под андроид на travis-ci.com, но получаю ошибку в ходе релиза на гх (компиляция сама проходит успешно).

```
$ dpl releases --token $GITHUB_TOKEN --file "bin/soulbuddy-0.0.1-armeabi-v7a-debug.apk" --tag_name "v.0.0.1"
Too many arguments: bin/soulbuddy-0.0.1-armeabi-v7a-debug.apk (given: 1, allowed: 0)
The command "dpl releases --token $GITHUB_TOKEN --file "bin/soulbuddy-0.0.1-armeabi-v7a-debug.apk" --tag_name "v.0.0.1"" failed and exited with 1 during .
```

При этом, когда я компилирую другое свое приложение (тестовое), релиз происходит успешно без ошибок.

```
4.83s$ dpl releases --token $GITHUB_TOKEN --file "bin/yyapp-0.5.2-armeabi-v7a-debug.apk" --tag_name "v.0.7.2"
Installing deployment dependencies
```

В чем может заключаться проблема?
Заранее спасибо за помощь! <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для каждого репозитория на travis-ci требуется указывать токен. В моем случае GITHUB_TOKEN был только в тестовом. В основном же отсутствовал, что и вызвало ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в файле buildozer.spec параметру ios.codesign.allowed присвоить значение true. В моём случае сработало

Comment: Проблема решена, проблема заключалась в другом (решение написал). Спасибо за помощь! <3